# Ctrl+PgUp on numeric keypad not working

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, numpad

The numeric keypad on my laptop is not working with modifier keys. For example, the keys to switch tabs are <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd> in Nautilus and Gnome Terminal and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd> in gedit. These keys work when I use the <kbd>PgUp</kbd> key next to right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, but they don't work in these programs when I am using <kbd>PgUp</kbd> on the numeric keypad. However, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd> does switch tabs in Firefox and Chrome. Without the modifier keys the numpad keys work fine. For example, I can move around using arrows and <kbd>PgUp</kbd>/<kbd>PgDn</kbd> in gedit.

NumLock and Universal Access > Mouse Keys are turned off. In Gnome Tweaks I set "Num Lock off: arrow keys (as in Windows)" under "Miscellaneous compatibility options", but it does not seem to make a difference. I am using Ubuntu 19.04 with Gnome and X11.