# Ubuntu 22.04: Gnome terminal: ctrl + {pgup, pgdown} does not work (and it's sooo annoying)

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, firefox, gnome-terminal

I have a problem that looks very similar to the one described here: [Ctrl+PgUp on numeric keypad not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1174100/ctrlpgup-on-numeric-keypad-not-working)

On my Dell Precision 3560 running Ubuntu 22.04 I have a problem where I cannot "scroll" tabs using keyboard in neither Firefox nor Gnome terminal. Ctrl + pgup (and down) seem to be working just fine on other machines, but not in this one, and this is quite annoying. Turning numlock on and off does not change a thing.

Somewhere in the Internet I have found solution to similar issues in older Ubuntu version, and it was to turn off "Mouse keys" in Accessibility settings. However, it seems like there is no such option in Ubuntu 22.

I'm wondering if it's something local to Gnome(GTK) or is it system-wise problem and more importantly : how to diagnose & fix this.

Comment: Did you check the settings for Gnome Terminal? Open Gnome Terminal Settings and then select keyboard shortcuts from the menu on the left and check the shortcut set for switching tabs. It should be noted that if CTRL+PgUp or CTRL+PgDn are in use by another application, the conflict will prevent you from setting it here. So if you need to, check the default keyboard shortcuts in your desktop settings to verify it's not already in use there. If so, then you will need to remove that shortcut before setting it in your Gnome Terminal settings.

Comment: Hey, yes, shortcut settings are as they should be.